# Embedded ActiveMQ SimpleAuthenticationPlugin not working; queue allows all connections

Tags: activemq-classic, spring-jms, spring-boot-starter

I'm using the **spring-boot-activemq-starter** to set up an ***embedded broker with a queue***.  Since I'm using an embedded broker with this project, I have a feeling that spring boot is not properly picking up the SimpleAuthentication plugin that i have in my resources folder as well as the /conf folder normally found in the standalone ActiveMQ

```
<plugins>
   <simpleAuthenticationPlugin anonymousAccessAllowed="false">
     <users>
         <authenticationUser username="myUser" password="myPassword" groups="users,admins"/>
     </users>
   </simpleAuthenticationPlugin>
</plugins>
```

**I'm finding that the broker is allowing any connection regardless of the username/password being sent on the request.**  This will make people angry if my app gets DOXXED.  I will also be angry.
I do not like it when people are angry with me.

Since the guides I'm following generally use a standalone instance of ActiveMQ, I'm hoping someone can guide me to the corresponding configs I may need to set in a properties file for Spring Boot.  *Or if there is an alternative approach I should take, please let me know.*

Answer (score 0):

You need to add authorization plugin entries as well.

Sample from the docs:

```
<authorizationPlugin> 
    <map> 
      <authorizationMap> 
        <authorizationEntries> 
          <authorizationEntry queue="TEST.Q" read="users" write="users" admin="users" /> 
          <authorizationEntry topic="ActiveMQ.Advisory.>" read="*" write="*" admin="*"/> 
        </authorizationEntries> 
        <tempDestinationAuthorizationEntry> 
          <tempDestinationAuthorizationEntry read="admins" write="admins" admin="admins"/> 
        </tempDestinationAuthorizationEntry> 
      </authorizationMap> 
    </map> 
  </authorizationPlugin>
```

ref: https://activemq.apache.org/security